# Index error when filling in an array with a randomly generated array

Tags: matlab

I am getting an error when running this bit of code about the index.  I have ran through the logic several times and have yet to catch my error and I am thinking it is in the way I coded this section.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if I am missing any information vital for this bit of code.

```
index_pairs = [1,12661;12662,46147;46148,52362]    
group_class_count = [10137,2524;127448,20738;1570,4645]
group_count = 3
cross_sections = 10

for j=1:group_count
    rand_index=randsample(index_pairs(j,1):index_pairs(j,2),(group_class_count(j,1)+group_class_count(j,2)),true);  % Creates an index of random rows for the current group.
    cross_size(j)=floor(size(rand_index,2)/cross_sections);
    for k=1:cross_sections
        cross_rand_indices(j,k)={rand_index(cross_size*(k-1)+1:cross_size*(k))};
    end
 end

error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions. Error in cross_rand_indices(j,k)={rand_index(cross_size*(k-1)+1:cross_size*(k))};
```

Comment: I went ahead and set replacement to true in order to replicate the original error.

Comment: Could it be related to your use of `cross_size` instead of `cross_size(j)` in your `k`-loop?

Comment: This error indeed throws an error. for j=3 and k=5 it tries to access cross_size at index k-1 which equals 4. But at that point cross_size only is of size 1x3.

Comment: @Nras I'm not sure any index from `cross_size` is being accessed - it appears that `cross_size` is multiplied by `(k-1)` and `(k)`,

Comment: @Schorsch That appears to be true, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
cross_rand_indices(j,k)={rand_index(cross_size*(k-1)+1:cross_size*(k))};
```

to

```
cross_rand_indices(j,k)={rand_index(cross_size(j)*(k-1)+1:cross_size(j)*(k))};
```

the error will disappear.
I assume this is in line with your intent when saving something to `cross_size(j)` in the outer loop.